# Reading from PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf, extract

I am making a project that's related to reading documents. I have to read them in the PDF form , so i was wondering if there's a way to read from PDF file like reading from Word file . I'm using C# .

Comment: Go to your favourite search engine and type in `c# read pdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). It's an easy-to-use open source library

Comment: [nuget.org's  iTextSharp download](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/)